# rich placeholder can't input text as in placeholder

Tags: jsf, richfaces, placeholder

Is that a bug in rich:placeholder?

```
<h:inputText id="input">
    <rich:placeholder value="Type text here..." />
</h:inputText>
```

When i try to input text same as in placeholder it disappears.

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=placeholder

Type in Input text placeholder suggest "Type text here..."  — it disappears when leave input and focus in it again.
Any other symbols stays.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: A limitation of the implementation, why do you need to type in the placeholder value?

Comment: ok. I understand this. Will use smth like <rich:placeholder **value="ex. Type text here..."** />

Answer (score 0):

Use smth like:`<rich:placeholder value="ex. Type text here..." />`

Or don't use placeholder.